# Plotting data against alphabetical word

Tags: gnuplot

I have these set of data and i want to plot column2 against column1 using gnuplot. Please, how do i go about it?

```
France   643427
Spain    504782
Sweden   449964
Germany  357021
Finland  338145
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple command to achieve this is

```
plot 'test.txt' using 2:xticlabels(1) with linespoints notitle
```

The `xticlabels` function takes the strings from the first column and places them as custom ticlabels (similar to `set xtics add ('France' 0, 'Spain' 1, ...)`).

This gives (with version 4.6.3 and the `pngcairo` terminal):

[image]